# How to solve the OPTIONS 500 error in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a React Application to upload a file to the S3 bucket. To do this, I have created a PUT API from the AWS API Gateway and the API is working well in the POSTMAN. The **problem is, when I call the API from my React Application locally (http://localhost:3000), I'm getting a 500 error from the OPTIONS request (Preflight).**

I have set the Binary Media Types to "image/jpeg" and **When I remove the Binary Media Types, the API returns the 200 response**, but then, an empty image is uploaded without its content.

How can I solve this?

This is my Request Integrations of both the PUT method and the OPTIONS method

**PUT**

[image]

**OPTIONS**

[image]

Binary Media Types

[image]

Comment: any solution david we are facing this exact issue

Comment: @void by using "image/*" in the Binary Media Types solved my issue

Comment: @DavidJohns thanks for that! might be worth adding the solution as an answer. Cheers